# Madhava-Leibniz series in Intel x87

Tags: assembly, intel, x87

I teach a computer architecture class and am preparing examples of Intel i7 floating point processing for it.  The example algorithm is the Madhava-Leibniz series, which is a particularly slow way of calculating pi divided by 4.  (I am well aware of better algorithms, and this one is slow enough to see performance differences easily.)

There are three examples: first in C++, next using the x87 floating-point processor, and finishing with use of the AVX512 instruction set.

For the x87 example, I would like opinions as to whether the following code is reasonably efficient.  (I know the MMX/SSE/AVX instructions will be faster, and we will show those too.)  It is coded as inline assembly within Visual Studio 2017.

The C++ variables are: double term1 = 3.0, term2 = 5.0, workSum = 1.0, d4 = 4.0;

The code for which I solicit your opinion is:

```
    __asm {
        finit;  // Initialize x87
        fld1;   // starting value for result
        fld d4; // term increment amount for each loop iteration
        fld term2;  // starting second term (5)
        fld  term1; // starting first term (3)
        mov ecx,UINT_MAX    // loop limit
    LiebnizLoop: fld1;
        fdiv ST(0), ST(1);  // 1 / term1
        fld  ST(4)  // current result value
        fsub ST(0),ST(1)    // subtract 1 / term1
        fld1;   
        fdiv ST(0), ST(4);  // 1 / term2
        fadd ST(0), ST(1);  // add to current result value
        fstp ST(6); // save back
        ; // Logic to increment terms and continue loop
        fstp st(0); // pop st(0) to itself and delete;
        fstp st(0); 
        fld ST(2);  // get increment (4)
        fadd ST(0), ST(1);  // add to term1
        fst ST(1);  // save updated term 1
        fld ST(2);  // get term 2
        fadd ST(0),ST(4)    // add increment (4)
        fst ST(3);  // save updated term 2
        fstp st(0); // pop st(0) to itself and delete;
        fstp st(0); 
        loop LiebnizLoop    // loop
        fstp term1; // save ending term1, delete term2 and the increment
        fstp st(0); // 
        fstp st(0); // 
        fstp workSum; // save final result
    }
```

This generates a difference from the cmath.h M_PI value (divided by 4) of -0.000000000029105385, so I am fairly certain the result is accurate to ten decimal places of pi.
Thank you in advance for any thoughts you may provide!

Comment: From a quick glance, you use a lot of standalone `fstp st(0)` that could possibly be avoided. Unless you vectorize, the SSE version might not even be any faster.

Comment: To Jester: I agree, but that was the best way I found to pop values from the x87 stack without making a storage reference.  Locality is probably high enough that the cache would mask the time used, though.  And yes, the AVX512 example will be vectorized.

Comment: You don't need a storage reference. E.g. doing `fst st(3)` followed by `fstp st(0)` is equivalent to just `fstp st(3)`.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed the same thing as Jester.  Use `faddp st(1)` to add-and-pop, as well as using `fstp`.  And remember, you can `fadd st(4), st(0)`.  One of the operands has to be ST0, but it can be the source.

Comment: You can keep `1.0` as a constant deeper in the x87 stack and use `fdivr st(0), st(7)` for 1/x without destroying the `1`.  So you avoid those `fld1` instructions.  Even with the slow `loop` instruction ([Why is the loop instruction slow? Couldn't Intel have implemented it efficiently?](//stackoverflow.com/q/35742570)), this probably still bottlenecks on `fdiv` throughput or latency, though, regardless of clogging the front-end with `fld1` and `fstp`.

Comment: To Peter Cordes: Good point about the fdivr!   But I think I still have to get the divisor term into st(0), so I will be replacing the fld1 instruction with an fld st(1) at the start of the loop (as one example).  It seems like so much has to go through st(0) and one is constantly loading it for the next operation - or am I missing something?